# How to manipulate EPS files in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, eps

I am looking for an EPS library in Java. Our application generate images in different format on the server and we plan to add EPS support. I'd like the EPS library to be able to superimpose 2 images; foreground and background.
I did a quick search and the libraries I found do not seem ready for prime time.
Any recommendations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing leaps out, but it might be useful to simply reach out to [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) to do this, possibly via [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html) or [im4java](http://im4java.sourceforge.net/), or maybe just via `exec`.